# How to compute FN and TN explicitly?

Tags: classification, clustering, combinatorics

Suppose that we have the following clusters ( output of some clustering algorithm ) based on 3 classes :
[image]

Source : [Source link](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html#fig:clustfg3)

The source explains how to calculate **TP+FP** and **TP** explicitly as following :

[image]

I'm confused about how to calculate **TN+FN** and **TN** , I'm wanting to know how to calculate those measures **( using the same logic of Combinations )** ?

Thank you in advance for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FNs (d: diamond), you take pairs of different clusters that should have been in the same cluster:

- 5x in C1 and 1x in C2 --> 5
- 5x in C1 and 2x in C3 --> 10
- 2x in C3 and 1x in C2 --> 2
- 1o in C1 and 4o in C2 --> 4
- 1d in C2 and 3d in C3 --> 3

which sums up to 24.

The FN+TN is (TP+FP) subtracted from the total number of combinations:
$${17\choose 2}-40=96$$

Comment: thank you a lot for your precious help !

Comment: I accepted your answer. Your answer clarified plenty of things for me. Thank you a lot for the valuable help!